# How to determine whether a C++ template has specified method

Tags: c++, templates

Let's suppose I am writing a function template `GCD` which uses both `operator/` and `operator%`. For some types, for example, complex numbers or polynomials both can be computed efficiently (i.e. when dividing polynomials you get remainder "for free"). So some of my class templates have `divmod` implemented, which returns a pair of quotient and remainder.

However some classes and notably built-in types, such as `int`, do not have `divmod` (or equivalent) implemented. If I was about to write one `GCD` which uses `divmod` I would discriminate against the other types (and vice versa). I haven't been able to come up with a template specialization which wouldn't require most of the code for `GCD` to be repeated.

What are my options here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go for type traits and template specializations based on that. You can use metaprogramming to determine if the type has divmod, and based on that provide specific parts of a general algorithm. That is, extract the common part of the algorithm into a generic piece of code that calls specialized functions for the differing parts based on the typetraits.

Take a look at [boost::type_traits library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/index.html) to get on the way of the type traits implementation, and [policy based design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_design) for ideas on how to inject different behaviors in a common code base by means of (policy) templates.

Comment: thanks, I guess your answer and http://www.ddj.com/cpp/184404270#l4 will get me going!

Comment: ok, actually http://www.kuro5hin.org/?op=displaystory&sid=2001/3/1/72020/17594 did the trick